# Считывание массива и ошибка System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#

Есть олимпиадная задача:

> На выборах в Государственную думу в избирательные бюллетени внесено N
>   партий. Электронный сканер для считывания информации с бюллетеней
>   передает информацию о каждом бюллетене в следующем формате: если в
>   соответствующей клетке бюллетеня стоит пометка, то сканер передает +
>   (плюс), в противном случае он передает - (минус). Таким образом, он
>   передает последовательность из N символов - плюсов и минусов.
>
> Бюллетень считается действительным, если пометка есть ровно в одной
>   клетке. Недействительные бюллетени в подсчете результатов выборов не
>   участвуют.
>
> Партия проходит в Государственную Думу, только если она набирает не
>   менее 7% от общего числа действительных бюллетеней.
>
> Требуется вывести номера (в порядке их перечисления в бюллетене) всех
>   партий, которые проходят в Государственную Думу.
>
> Входные данные В первой строке входных данных содержатся два числа,
>   разделенные пробелом: N - количество партий и M - количество
>   бюллетеней. Оба числа натуральные, N <= 200, M <= 100 000.
>
> В следующих M строках записана информация, полученная из бюллетеней.
>   Каждая строка - последовательность из N символов + или - (без
>   пробелов).
>
> Гарантируется, что есть хотя бы один действительный бюллетень.
>
> Выходные данные Выведите через пробел номера партий, прошедших в Думу,
>   в порядке возрастания. Если ни одна из партий не проходит в Думу, 
>   выводить ничего не нужно.

Весь мой код:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        string[] votes;
        int count = 0;
        int consignments = int.Parse(temp[0]);
        int bulletins = int.Parse(temp[1]);
        int sum1;
        int sum2;
        int sum3;
        temp = null;

        for (int c = 0; c < consignments; c++)
        {
            votes = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(votes, "+")) count++;
            if (count != 1)
            {
                bulletins--;
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", votes, consignments, bulletins);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Есть переменная votes, в неё должен считываться массив строк (`+--`, или `-+-`, или `-+---`), но он не считывается, а в гугле нормальной инфы не нашёл...

```
string[] votes;
votes = Console.ReadLine();
```

---

Ещё, после кода:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(votes.ToString(), "+")) count++;
```

Вылезает:
[image: System.ArgumentException]

В чём ошибка?

Comment: вы знаете, что возвращает функция ToString() для массива? Выведите на консоль и увидите

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov , System.String[]

Comment: и в чем у вас проблема? У вас массив votes пустой? В его элементах неверные значения?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Нужно считать строку в массив, но я не понимаю как, т.к. все известные мне способы выдают ошибку в Visual Studio, А я знаю мало

Comment: кто вам сказал, что вы строку должны считать в массив? Вы великолепно считываете строку в элемент массива. Все прекрасно.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov , Я попробовал через `String.Concat<char>(votes)` преобразовать массив char в string и у меня получилось, в консоли всё ок, но выражение `foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(String.Concat<char>(votes), "+")) count++;` всё равно выдаёт ошибку как на скрине консоли.

Comment: Если вы хотите объединить массив строк в единую строку, то можно так String.Join("", votes)

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov , при любых манипуляциях строка `foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(..., "+"))` выдает одну и туже ошибку... (System.ArgumentException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил все проблемы массивом `char`

```
char[] votes;
votes = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
count = votes.Where(i => i == '+').Count();
```